# Syntax issue with BEGIN ... SET ... END

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have written the following stored procedure that uses a Date Dimension table to calculate the next occurrence of a date given a begin date and a frequency.

I am getting some odd syntax errors that seem to occur whenever I have an IF BEGIN SET IF SET END sequence.

In order to help debug, I have gone back in and added unneeded BEGIN and END statements around the one line IF statements.

Am I missing some type of BEGIN - END or IF - ELSE matching rule here? (I've marked the lines that the parser is complaining about with comments.)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetNextScheduledBusinessDayOccurance
(
  @BeginDate DATE,
  @Frequency CHAR(1)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Date DATETIME,
    @currentDate DATE,
    @weekOfYear INT,
    @dayOfWeek varchar(9),
    @weekOfMonth tinyint,
    @month varchar(2),
    @dayOfQuarter tinyint,
    @currentDayOfQuarter tinyint,
    @quarterOfNextOccurance tinyint,
    @yearOfNextOccurance int;

    SET @currentDate = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())
    IF (@BeginDate > @currentDate)-- If it hasn't started yet
    BEGIN
        SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) [DATE] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE [DATE] >= @BeginDate AND [Date] > @currentDate AND (IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [DATE])
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @Frequency = 'A' --Annually
            BEGIN
                SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) [DATE] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE ([DATE] > @currentDate AND [Month] >= DATEPART(MONTH, @BeginDate) AND [Day] >= DATEPART(DAY, @BeginDate) AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date])
            END
            ELSE IF @Frequency = 'B' --Biweekly
                BEGIN
                    SET @weekOfYear = (SELECT WeekOfYear FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @BeginDate)
                    SET @dayOfWeek = (SELECT [DayOfWeek] FROM Dbo.dim_Date WHERE [Date] >= @BeginDate AND IsBusinessDay = 1)
                    SET @Date = ((SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE ([DATE] > @currentDate AND [WeekOfYear]%2 = @weekOfYear%2 AND [DayOfWeek] = @dayOfWeek AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date]))
                END
            ELSE IF @Frequency = 'D' --Daily
                BEGIN
                    SET @Date = ((SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE ([DATE] > @currentDate AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date]))
                END
            ELSE IF @Frequency = 'E' -- Semi-Monthly (twice each month) (assume the 15th and last day of month)
                BEGIN
                    -- GET the next 15th or last day of month.
                    SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] > @currentDate AND (Day = '15' OR (DateAdd(day, -1, DateAdd( month, DateDiff(month , 0,[Date])+1 , 0)) = [Date])) ORDER BY [Date])
                    IF ((SELECT IsBusinessDay FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @Date) = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Date = ((SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE (([DATE] > @Date) AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date])
                    END --Parser ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
                END
            ELSE IF @Frequency = 'I' --Bimonthly (Every other month)
                BEGIN
                    SET @Month = (SELECT Month FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @BeginDate)
                    SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE ([Date] > @currentDate AND [Month]%2 = @Month%2 AND [Day] = DATEPART(day, @BeginDate)) ORDER BY [Date])
                    IF ((SELECT IsBusinessDay FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @Date) = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Date = ((SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE (([DATE] > @Date) AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date])
                    END --Parser ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
                END
            ELSE IF @Frequency = 'L' --Last Business Day of the Month
                BEGIN
                    SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] > '2013-03-20 00:00:00.000' AND  (DateAdd(day, -1, DateAdd( month, DateDiff(month , 0,[Date])+1 , 0)) = [Date]) ORDER BY [Date])
                    IF ((SELECT IsBusinessDay FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @Date) = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Date = ((SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE (([DATE] < @Date) AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date] DESC))
                    END
                END     
            ELSE IF @Frequency = 'M'  -- Monthly
                BEGIN
                    SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] > @currentDate AND (Day > DATEPART(day, @BeginDate)) ORDER BY [Date])
                    IF ((SELECT IsBusinessDay FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @Date) = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Date = ((SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE (([DATE] > @Date) AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date])
                    END--Parser ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
                END
            ELSE
            IF @Frequency = 'Q' --Quarterly
                BEGIN
                    SET @dayOfQuarter = (Select DayOfQuarter FROM dim_Date WHERE [DATE] = @BeginDate)
                    SET @currentDayOfQuarter = (Select DayOfQuarter FROM dim_Date WHERE [DATE] = @currentDate)
                    SET @quarterOfNextOccurance = (SELECT [Quarter] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @currentDate)
                    SET @yearOfNextOccurance = (SELECT [Year] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @currentDate)
                    --SELECT @dayOfQuarter DOQ, @currentDayOfQuarter curDOQ, @quarterOfNextOccurance QofNext, @yearOfNextOccurance YofNext
                    IF (@currentDayOfQuarter >= @dayOfQuarter)
                        SET @quarterOfNextOccurance = @quarterOfNextOccurance + 1
                    SET @Date = '1900-01-01'
                    WHILE (@Date < @currentDate) --Loop through this just in case we're close to the end of the Quarter, and there's no more business days left
                        BEGIN
                            IF (@quarterOfNextOccurance > 4)
                                BEGIN
                                    SET @quarterOfNextOccurance = @quarterOfNextOccurance%4
                                    SET @yearOfNextOccurance = @yearOfNextOccurance + 1         
                                END
                            --SELECT @quarterOfNextOccurance QofNext, @yearOfNextOccurance YofNext
                            --CREATE a temp table with all of the business dates from the target quarter in decending order.
                            SELECT * INTO ##temp FROM (SELECT TOP(92) [Date], MAX(DayOfQuarter) as DOQ FROM dim_Date WHERE (YEAR = @yearOfNextOccurance AND Quarter = @quarterOfNextOccurance AND IsBusinessDay = 1) Group By Date ORDER BY Date DESC) as foo
                            SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) DATE from ##temp WHERE DOQ <= @dayOfQuarter)
                            SET @quarterOfNextOccurance = @quarterOfNextOccurance + 1 -- Go ahead and incriment this just in case we start the WHILE over.
                            --SELECT * FROM ##temp
                            BEGIN TRY DROP TABLE ##temp END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH
                        END
                END
            ELSE
            IF @Frequency = 'S' --Semi-annually
                BEGIN
                    SET @Date = @BeginDate
                    WHILE (@Date < @currentDate)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Date = (SELECT [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE [Date] = DATEADD(MONTH, 6, @Date))
                    END
                    IF ((SELECT IsBusinessDay FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @Date) = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Date = ((SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE (([DATE] > @Date) AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date])
                    END--Parser ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
                END
            ELSE
            IF @Frequency = 'W' --Weekly
                BEGIN
                    SET @dayOfWeek = (SELECT [DayOfWeek] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @BeginDate)
                    SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM Dbo.dim_Date WHERE DayOfWeek = @dayOfWeek AND [DATE] < @currentDate ORDER BY [DATE] DESC)
                    --SELECT @Date DATE, @BeginDate BeginDate
                    WHILE ((@Date < @currentDate) OR (@Date < @BeginDate))
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Date = (SELECT [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE [Date] = DATEADD(Week, 1, @Date))
                        --SELECT @Date DateInWHile
                    END
                    IF ((SELECT IsBusinessDay FROM dim_Date WHERE [Date] = @Date) = 0)
                        SET @Date = (SELECT TOP(1) [Date] FROM dbo.dim_Date WHERE (([DATE] > @Date) AND IsBusinessDay = 1) ORDER BY [Date])
                    --SELECT @Date
                END
            ELSE
                SET @Date = NULL
        END
        RETURN @Date
END

GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)`:

```
BEGIN
  SET @Date = ((
    SELECT TOP(1) [Date] 
    FROM dbo.dim_Date 
    WHERE (([DATE] > @Date) AND IsBusinessDay = 1) 
    ORDER BY [Date]) ) -- Paren added here...
END --Parser ERROR: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
```

Comment: @NathanC You're welcome... throwing the code into a different IDE that highlights matching parens can be helpful.  In this case I just put it into notepad++...

Comment: SSMS 2012 does a pretty good job at paren matching, so that is an option too (especially now that it's completely free). You can still manage older versions and it will save swapping code between editors.